# SEAL: How to read Relinkeys data in forms of modulo coefficients?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, seal

When running examples in SEAL (v3.6), I can print out polynomial coefficients of `secret_key`, `public_key` data using support functions

```
ofstream sk;
sk.open(filename, ios::binary);
for (uint64_t i = 0; i < poly_modulus_degree; i++)
{
    sk << secret_key.data()[i] << endl;
}
sk.close();
```

with the coefficient data layout follow moduli is same with [Simple Encrypted Arithmetic Library (SEAL) and the seal::Ciphertext variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416347/simple-encrypted-arithmetic-library-seal-and-the-sealciphertext-variable).

Output coefficients 60 bits as examples:

```
348362126124274227
287021082413421529
790977662641979136
532895062119300067
...
```

But I can not understand the forms of `relin_keys` and how to use its class's support methods to print `relin_keys` data in forms of polynomial coefficients?
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RelinKeys` is derived from `KSwitchKeys` which contains a data member in the type of `vector<vector<PublicKey>>`. Since `PublicKey` is basically the same with `Ciphertext`, `RelinKeys` is simply a 2-dimensional vector of `Ciphertext`.

The first dimension enumerates the relinearization key generated for a certain power of secret key. For example, by default only a relinearization key for the 2nd power of secret key is generated, therefore **the first dimension usually has size `1`**. This is accessible by `relin_keys.key(2)` described by [this method](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/f70b4dc6ab57ff743fa63177f8a9798913a27c68/native/src/seal/relinkeys.h#L81), which returns `vector<PublicKey>`.

The second dimension corresponds to the decomposition method used to generated relinearization keys and to perform relinearization. The size of the second dimension is usually equal to `context.first_context_data()->parms().coeff_modulus().size()`. After this point, you should know how to print out each `Ciphertext` object.

The following code should help:

```cpp
void print_ciphertext(const Ciphertext &ciphertext) {
    // code to print coefficients of a Ciphertext object
}

RelinKeys relin_keys;
// ... generate keys ...

for (std::size_t key_power = 2; relin_keys.has_key(key_power); key_power++) {
    for (auto &public_key: relin_keys.key(key_power)) {
        print_ciphertext(public_key.data());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I can print out the relin_keys and its relative ciphetexts in evaluator.cpp file.